# Drag and Drop QLabels with PyQt5 Pixmap and text

Tags: python-3.x, drag-and-drop, pyqt5, qlabel

I find the same question with this title in a question of about 11 months ago. What I miss there is: How do I drag and drop a Qlabel, where I can copy the Pixmap AND the text of the label.

I will have several QLabel with different Pixmaps. With drag an drop i am going to fill another label (my goal-label). There, I want to see the picture (Pixmap) and want to read the text of the label, because I want to do another action, depending, from which of the QLabels I filled my goal level

With the answers of the mentioned question i am able to copy either the text or the Pixmap, never both.

I try to explain the code beneath:
in the draggable label i see my text and the picture. In the init-section I print self.text() and get the correct text from the call. But in the mouseMoveEvent, the self.text() is empty.
When I setText(...) later, this text can be evaluated in the drop-event of my goal-label.
ONLY the copy of the Pxmap works here.

Question: How do I get the selt.text() INTO my mouseMoveEvent?

```
class DraggableLabel(QLabel):
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.setText = args[0]
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)
    print("my text in init ", self.text())


def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
        self.drag_start_position = event.pos()

def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
    print("where is the text?", self.text())
    if not (event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton):
        return
    if (event.pos() - self.drag_start_position).manhattanLength() < QApplication.startDragDistance():
        return
    drag = QDrag(self)
    mimedata = QMimeData()
    mimedata.setText('this text works')
    print("text in mimedata",self.text(), " und ",mimedata.text())
    mimedata.setImageData(self.pixmap().toImage())
    drag.setMimeData(mimedata)
    pixmap = QPixmap(self.size())
    painter = QPainter(pixmap)
    painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.grab())
    painter.end()
    drag.setPixmap(pixmap)
    drag.setHotSpot(event.pos())
    drag.exec_(Qt.CopyAction | Qt.MoveAction)

class my_label(QLabel):
def __init__(self,title,parent):
    super().__init__(title,parent)
    self.setAcceptDrops(True)
    pixmap = QPixmap('/home/jf/PycharmProjects/Einzelnoten-1.jpg')
    self.setPixmap(pixmap) 


def dragEnterEvent(self,event):
    if event.mimeData().hasImage():
        print("event accepted")
        event.accept()
    else:
        print("event rejected")
        event.ignore()

def dropEvent(self,event):
    if event.mimeData().hasImage():
        text = event.mimeData().text()
        self.setPixmap(QPixmap(event.mimeData().imageData()))
        print("mimetext",event.mimeData().text())
```

`

```
class Widget(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    label = my_label("muh",self) #DropLabel("drop there",self)
    label.setGeometry(190, 65, 100,100)
    label_to_drag = DraggableLabel("mist", self) #image) #"/home/jf/PycharmProjects/Image.png", self)   #("Einzelnoten-1.jpg", self)
    image=QPixmap("/home/jf/PycharmProjects/Image.png")
    label_to_drag.setPixmap((image))
    self.show()
```

P.S. Sorry, but I do not get the code correct, that class and def are on different levels
(Working in Ubuntu 18 with python3,6)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set a `QPixmap` to your label, it loses its text. So, you can save the labels text before setting the pixmap:

```
class DraggableLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setText(args[0])
        self._text = None
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        print("my text in init ", self.text())


    def setPixmap(self, pixmap):
        if pixmap.isNull():
            self._text = None
        else:
            self._text = self.text()
        super().setPixmap(pixmap)

    def text(self):
        if self._text:
            return self._text
        return super().text()
```